# django leaflet_map how to add geojson layer on demand

Tags: django, leaflet

I have a geodjango project using django-leaflet. A base map is displayed in the body of the html file using  {% leaflet_map "mapid" %} . No other initialization is needed for the base map to display. Also, there is a choice box of polygon features that user can select. Upon selection the selected feature should display on top of the base map. As shown, the selected feature is the success response of a post ajax call. I get the correct data, however, I don't know how to display it on the map.

```
<html>
<head>
    {% load leaflet_tags %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    {% leaflet_js %}
    <style>
        #mapid {
          width: 870px;
          height: 530px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> {% leaflet_map "mapid" %} </div>
    <form id="aoi-form" method="post" action="" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select id="aoi-choice" name="modelarea_sel_name" >
            {% for aoi in modelarea.aois.field.choices %}
                <option>{{aoi|title}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // sets the csrf token for all the ajax calls
        setCSRFToken();   

        function displayModelArea(data) {
            window.addEventListener("map:init", function(event) {
                var map = event.detail.map;
                L.geoJson(data, {
                    onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
                    }
                }).addTo(map);
            });
        }   

        $('#aoi-choice').on('change', function(e) {
            var selecteditem = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:      $("#aoi-form").attr("action"),
                type:     $("#aoi-form").attr("method"),
                data:     { "aoi-choice": selecteditem },      
                success:  function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    <How to add this geojson to the map in success?>
                    <something like:>
                    displayModelArea(response) // this is not working
                },  
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {}
            }); // end of ajax
        }); // end of on change
      }); // end of document
    </script>
</body>
</html> 

views.py
def rsmgui_home(request):

    template_name = 'rsmgui_nav.html'

    if request.POST.get("aoi-choice"):
        polydata = serialize('geojson', ModelArea.objects.filter(name=request.POST.get("aoi-choice")))
        return JsonResponse(polydata, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the solution, I must say, my original code contained two mistakes:

1) Had to return HttpResponse instead of JsonResponse from the views.py.

2) Had to initialize and get handle of the map (i.e. mymap) outside of the $(document).ready. Although, I am sure I should be able to do the same with jquery, But I did not know how!

FYI - the data format returned from views was somethings like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "objectid": 3235,
    "name": "WCU-L38E-2",
    "shape_area": 5178189.95436,
    "shape_len": 20962.4168727,
    "model": "rsmgui.modelarea"
    },
    "id": 3,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates":
        [[[[-80.4431746089703, 26.1496150525031], [-80.4438712320284, 26.1494779568429], [-80.4438714835869, 26.1494791485814],
           [-80.4438767327393, 26.1495038898062], [-80.443876985872, 26.1495050844166], [-80.4439596517546, 26.1498945523],
           [-80.4439599048889, 26.1498957469102], [-80.4445181371852, 26.1525257445301], [-80.444518396688, 26.1525269377307],
           [-80.4454063419315, 26.1566079785707], [-80.4454066030393, 26.1566091717754], [-80.4454367956768, 26.1567473825391],
           [-80.4454269367566, 26.1568310621773], [-80.4454019935245, 26.1569010164227], [-80.4451487080981, 26.1572161211586],
           [-80.4451198504533, 26.1572690055153], [-80.4451124234237, 26.1572826141087], [-80.4450987418606, 26.1573731140696],
           [-80.4451097451673, 26.1574483323541], [-80.4451099518947, 26.1574492731537], [-80.4454045318579, 26.1587738519124],
           [-80.4454291560893, 26.1588281989547], [-80.4454726925214, 26.158873231686], [-80.4454745412333, 26.1588751446035],
           [-80.4457224526486, 26.1590556968988], [-80.4459825369665, 26.1592924192246], [-80.4460113732483, 26.1593318182711],
           [-80.446029694147, 26.1594029793378], [-80.4460299489157, 26.1594041725167], [-80.4461426842445, 26.1599298599992],
           [-80.4461429406032, 26.159931053184], [-80.4461632993508, 26.1600259843658], [-80.4461635557098, 26.1600271775505],
           [-80.4461662854139, 26.1600399110449], [-80.446166541773, 26.1600411042296], [-80.4461669349025, 26.1600429241313],
           [-80.4461698308018, 26.1600564420782], [-80.4461703745794, 26.1600589761589], [-80.4461706309386, 26.1600601693436],
           [-80.4461724673901, 26.1600687195423], [-80.446172720567, 26.1600699141476], [-80.4461890554485, 26.1601460828104],
           [-80.4461892651751, 26.1601470637419], [-80.4461894764895, 26.1601480446796], [-80.4464055948207, 26.1611557705659],
           [-80.4464058511845, 26.1611569637501], [-80.4465182479751, 26.1616803740569], [-80.446518504341, 26.1616815672408],
           [-80.4467438353217, 26.1627308699823], [-80.4467440932799, 26.1627320631719], [-80.4471482872166, 26.1646036789173],
           [-80.4471485483585, 26.1646048721181], [-80.4483626433148, 26.1701518069936], [-80.4483628854181, 26.1701530015516],
           [-80.4483814524309, 26.1702450510074], [-80.4483896526105, 26.1703196621089], [-80.44837083869, 26.1703813120244],
           [-80.4483349119681, 26.1704454670367], [-80.448238820436, 26.1705762562447], [-80.4480865737154, 26.1708302726741],
           [-80.4480562687647, 26.1709111657153], [-80.4480474043405, 26.1709779965095], [-80.4480570552683, 26.1710631695728],
           [-80.4480726187489, 26.1711178954947], [-80.4480728735615, 26.1711190886688], [-80.448600444514, 26.1735684214603],
           [-80.4486318283615, 26.1736785332924], [-80.4486793668728, 26.1737445068659], [-80.4492087688318, 26.1741548565954],
           [-80.4492476879068, 26.1742313275962], [-80.4492734967374, 26.1743198523785], [-80.4492737277215, 26.1743210511907],
           [-80.4493637707618, 26.174788553371], [-80.4494647807674, 26.1752251203668], [-80.4494649710993, 26.1752261843278],
           [-80.4495030325796, 26.1754400354424], [-80.4495075156305, 26.1755698630249], [-80.4494919585678, 26.1757079020217],
           [-80.4494654601658, 26.1758137385183], [-80.4494247803613, 26.1759047014177], [-80.4493654321733, 26.1760018949102],
           [-80.449291361239, 26.1760990334811], [-80.449224827617, 26.1761585592545], [-80.4490944858737, 26.176220056103],
           [-80.448817683956, 26.176319577968], [-80.4486133770828, 26.176391343208], [-80.448294685515, 26.1764133756087],
           [-80.4482742214126, 26.1764147902816], [-80.4482629422319, 26.1764173105563], [-80.4482608358316, 26.1764177810802],
           [-80.4481701381423, 26.1764380517997], [-80.4480857500865, 26.1764548904322], [-80.4480278075929, 26.1764455275992],
           [-80.4479938505702, 26.1764255169321], [-80.4447866204566, 26.1616803278906], [-80.4427502472453, 26.1523162458952],
           [-80.4425042672057, 26.1511130652601], [-80.4424324383669, 26.1508789484218], [-80.4422838184404, 26.1506638659222],
           [-80.442263580685, 26.150586872045], [-80.4422584377825, 26.1505622200219], [-80.4422537121117, 26.1505393091941],
           [-80.4422484417484, 26.1505144173773], [-80.4422447794031, 26.1504939380542], [-80.4422409109672, 26.1504737273243],
           [-80.4422344502975, 26.1504440606653], [-80.4422140566669, 26.1500502089701], [-80.4421980585152, 26.1498452491223],
           [-80.4421989899204, 26.149844702483], [-80.4422962649397, 26.149811382303], [-80.4423241174424, 26.1498018149787],
           [-80.442339856439, 26.1497964493973], [-80.4423577440382, 26.1497903226474], [-80.4423887913014, 26.1497796872474],
           [-80.4424405282263, 26.1497619686973], [-80.4424639436836, 26.1497539446344], [-80.4424890564009, 26.1497459185392],
           [-80.4426580984819, 26.1496918891336], [-80.4431746089703, 26.1496150525031]]]]}}],
    "crs": {
        "type": "link",
        "properties": {
            "href": "http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/",
            "type": "proj4"
        }
    }
};
```

Corrected code:

```
<html>
<head>

{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% leaflet_css %}
{% leaflet_js %}

<style>
    #mapid {
      width: 870px;
      height: 530px;
    } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    {% leaflet_map "mapid" %}
</div>
<form id="aoi-form" method="post" action="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="aoi-choice" name="modelarea_sel_name" >
        {% for aoi in modelarea.aois.field.choices %}
            <option>{{aoi|title}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mymap;
    window.addEventListener("map:init", function (event) {
        mymap = event.detail.map;
    }, false);

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function displayModelArea(map, data) {
            L.marker([26.92, -81.5]).addTo(mymap);       
            L.geoJSON(data).addTo(mymap);
        }

        $('#aoi-choice').on('change', function(e) {
            var selecteditem = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:      $("#aoi-form").attr("action"),
                type:     $("#aoi-form").attr("method"),
                data:     { "aoi-choice": selecteditem },      
                success:  function(response) {
                    displayModelArea(mymap, response)
            },  
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {}
        }); // end of ajax
    }); // end of on change
  }); // end of document
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def rsmgui_home(request):

    template_name = 'rsmgui_nav.html'

    if request.POST.get("aoi-choice"):
        polydata = serialize('geojson', ModelArea.objects.filter(name=request.POST.get("aoi-choice")))
        return HttpResponse(polydata, content_type='json')
```